# How to correctly implement python __iter__ on a class?

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to replicate python list iteration but unlike python lists my loop index doesn't restart inside nested loops.

Currently the 1st case works as expected but second case loops forever as the inner and outer loop both share the same myClassObj, and the inner loop always resets the index to starting value so outer loop never terminates. How to make it behave like python builtin lists?

```
class MyClass:
    """Iterator for looping over a sequence."""
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.data = seq
        self.index = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Return the next element, or else raise StopIteration error."""
        self.index += 1
        if self.index < len(self.data):
            return self.data[self.index]
        else:
            self.index = -1
            raise StopIteration()


myClassObj = MyClass('spa')

# Case1: This Works fine:
for i in range(2):
    for each in myClassObj:
        print(each)
    print()
print()

# Case2: This does not work correctly.
for each in myClassObj:
    for each1 in myClassObj:
        print('{}: {}'.format(each, each1))
    print()
```

Expected Behaviour for 2nd case is:

```
s: s
s: p
s: a

p: s
p: p
p: a

a: s
a: p
a: a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that your code is not working because self.index is shared by each and each1 (because they are both using the same instance of MyClass, myClassObj)
Try this:

```
class SeqIter:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self._seq = seq
        self._i = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self._i >= len(self._seq):
            raise StopIteration
        next_item = self._seq[self._i]
        self._i += 1
        return next_item


class Seq:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self._seq = seq

    def __iter__(self):
        return SeqIter(self._seq)
```

Running the test code:

```
seq = 'spa'
seq_obj = Seq(seq)
for i in seq_obj:
    for j in seq_obj:
        print(i, j)
```